# Batch-file: how to backup all .doc files to a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, backup

I have this small script that is intended to backup all `*.doc` files in the folder into a `_z` subfolder. I have just noticed it does not work properly, when `_` is part of the filename of the `*.doc` that is supposed to be backed up.

Could anyone kindly explain to me the source of the issue and perhaps advice on how to correct it, please?

```
mkdir _z
copy *.doc _z\*"_""%date:/=-%"" ""%time::=-%".doc
```

Comment: don't stray quotes at "random" locations. Quote the whole path *once* (like @Gerhard did)

Comment: @Gerhard
Thank you for your kind reply!
Sadly, it does not work for me.

using
`for %%i in (*.doc) do copy "%%~i" "_z\%~ni_%date:/=-% %time::=-%%%~xi"`

in a batch gives me the following:
`The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~ni_%date:/=-% %time::=-%%%~xi"

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\test>for %i in (*.doc) do copy "%~i" "_z\z\%~ni_%date:/=-% %time::=-%%%~xi"`

Any idea why, pls?

Comment: @Gerhard
I understand part of your answer, just not all of it. Although I try, my knowledge of Command prompt is limited and most of the usage of % and ~ is a total mystery to me :-( If you can point me to some good source, pls do. Most of what I find is just a list of commands or examples. Didn't find a really good book either. Note that although I am not a programmer, I work with VBA, AHK and Automate w/o problems. Still not as good as a real programmer :-)

Comment: you forgot a `%` : `"_z\%~ni_...` should be `"_z\%%~ni_...`

Comment: @Stephan, yeah that one is on me. I did not add it to my comment.

Comment: @Gerhard thank you very much again. It works beautifully and will be of great help in the future! Sadly I probably lack enough credit here to mark your answer as the solution. For anybody looking for a quick fix, here is Gerhard's final version that works so nicely: `mkdir _z` `for %%i in (*.doc) do copy "%%~i" "_z\%%~ni_%date:/=-% %time::=-%%%~xi"`

Comment: You do not lack reputation to mark answers. I just did not post one. It was simply an answer in a comment. :) glad it helped. Will post an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are telling it to copy everything up to the underscore, if one exists, else it will create one if it does not. That way the text after underscore is ignored. try a for loop

```
@echo off
mkdir "_z">nul 2>&1
for %%i in (*.doc) do copy "%%~i" "_z\%%~ni_%date:/=-% %time::=-%%%~xi"
```